# Adding header files to the C++ library recursively from an external library

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use an external library in my current C++ project. The header files in the library are in multiple folders and I need to add them into my make file (using cmake). I can add the header files by declaring each folder separately and ask the make file to find all header files in the folder. But is there a way to add all the headers inside multiple folders in one line of code?
Here's my cmake code for adding the headers in separate folders:

```
FILE (GLOB LibraryFolderOneHeaders ExternalLibrary/ExternalLibraryFolderOne/*.h)
FILE (GLOB LibraryFolderTwoHeaders ExternalLibrary/ExternalLibraryFolderTwo/*.h)

SOURCE_GROUP("Header Files\\LibraryFolderOne" FILES ${LibraryFolderOneHeaders})
SOURCE_GROUP("Header Files\\LibraryFolderTwo" FILES ${LibraryFolderTwoHeaders })
...
```

For all the folders.
Is there a way to find header files all at once?

Thanks

Comment: don't do this, rather use CMake's `find_package`: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries

Comment: @m.s.: As fas as I understand the question, the author wants to **add headers into IDE**. `find_package` does other things. (But result of `find_package` may be used when GLOB-ing headers).

Comment: I'm trying to use xgboost in my code. I used my own method to refer to header and source codes. I can compile my code. But now, when I use any of the functions in the library, it gives me "unresolved external symbol" error. Any clue?